# AES Encryption with C# Decryption with crypto-js

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, encryption

I'm triying to Encrypt string with C# and decrypt it using Angular crypto-js library but it's giving me different output.
I tried different c# aes encryption implementations but crypto-js library can't decrypt the encrypted data in c#. Thank you for any help.

Here is my code

Program.cs

```
 static void Main()
    {
        var r = EncryptString("exampleString", "examplePassword");
        Console.Write(r);
    }

 public static string EncryptString(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
        {
            return "";
        }
        // generate salt
        byte[] key, iv;
        var salt = new byte[8];
        var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
        DeriveKeyAndIv(passPhrase, salt, out key, out iv);
        // encrypt bytes
        var encryptedBytes = EncryptStringToBytesAes(plainText, key, iv);
        // add salt as first 8 bytes
        var encryptedBytesWithSalt = new byte[salt.Length + encryptedBytes.Length + 8];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Salted__"), 0, encryptedBytesWithSalt, 0, 8);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, encryptedBytesWithSalt, 8, salt.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytesWithSalt, salt.Length + 8, encryptedBytes.Length);
        // base64 encode
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytesWithSalt);
    }
    private static void DeriveKeyAndIv(string passPhrase, byte[] salt, out byte[] key, out byte[] iv)
    {
        // generate key and iv
        var concatenatedHashes = new List<byte>(48);
        var password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passPhrase);
        var currentHash = new byte[0];
        var md5 = MD5.Create();
        bool enoughBytesForKey = false;
        // See http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html#KEY_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM
        while (!enoughBytesForKey)
        {
            var preHashLength = currentHash.Length + password.Length + salt.Length;
            var preHash = new byte[preHashLength];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(currentHash, 0, preHash, 0, currentHash.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(password, 0, preHash, currentHash.Length, password.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, preHash, currentHash.Length + password.Length, salt.Length);
            currentHash = md5.ComputeHash(preHash);
            concatenatedHashes.AddRange(currentHash);
            if (concatenatedHashes.Count >= 48)
                enoughBytesForKey = true;
        }
        key = new byte[32];
        iv = new byte[16];
        concatenatedHashes.CopyTo(0, key, 0, 32);
        concatenatedHashes.CopyTo(32, iv, 0, 16);
        md5.Clear();
    }

    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytesAes(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");
        // Declare the stream used to encrypt to an in memory
        // array of bytes.
        MemoryStream msEncrypt;
        // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
        // used to encrypt the data.
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;
        try
        {
            // Create a RijndaelManaged object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, KeySize = 256, BlockSize = 128, Key = key, IV = iv };
            // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
            using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    //Write all data to the stream.
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    swEncrypt.Flush();
                    swEncrypt.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
            aesAlg?.Clear();
        }
        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }
```

Simply decrypting it using crypto-js

```
 let CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
let r = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt('exampleString', 'examplePassword').toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code is attempting to decrypt the original unencrypted string, which looks to be a mistake perhaps created when trying to simplify the example code for posting the question? Either way the steps required are not too difficult, but the toString() call needs to be replaced.

```
var data = "U2FsdGVkX1/Zvh/5BnLfUgfbg5ROSD7Aohumr9asPM8="; // Output from C#
let r2 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, 'examplePassword'));
console.log(r2);
```

Comment: Yes exatly. I was triying to simplify the code. Thank you. Now decrypt process is successfull.